# What is the difference between boot loader and bootstrap loader?

Tags: boot, bootloader

How is a boot loader different from a bootstrap loader?

According to me, bootstrap loaders are stored in ROM and boot loaders are on a hard disk in the MBR (please correct me if I am wrong). A bootstrap loader is the first program which gets executed after startup.

Now I am not getting the meaning of these sentences:

- *After power on, the bootloader is controlling the board and does not rely on the linux kernel on any way*.
- *The bootstrap loader acts as a glue between the bootloader and the linux kernel*.

What does it mean and why do we require both of them?

Comment: This is a good question, but where did you get those two lines from? Could you [edit] your question and add the link for context?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for a bootstrap has been left out from the answer above.. though there is a lot of good info here.

A bootstrap is designed NEVER to change and with minimal functionality. It may have the ability to choose between boot images or update a boot image, but it will lack all the drivers and support that a boot loader might have. A boot loader will usually setup almost all the hardware in a system prior to booting the OS, and may perform diagnostics, and ultimately update and boot the OS. The boot loader in many ways it can be like a mini OS where the bootstrap is completely minimalist and designed never to change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the boostrap loader is basically the first thing loaded after the bios or loaded simultaneously with uefi on computers that have it. It is what selects the hard drive to load from or, in the case of uefi, starts the OS entirely. The bootloader is usually contained in the mbr on bios systems (though grub extends a little beyond the official size of the mbr using links to other parts of the disk and most of it resides in the /boot partition or mount point in the installation partition) or the efi partition on uefi systems. The bootstrap loader is almost completely integrated with the bios on uefi systems and even partially the bootloader on some in some cases. The bootstrap loader, or in many cases the bios for this, sends the init signal to all connected parts of the computer but the bootloader is what actually detects and starts them completely. The bootstrap loader kind of blends software and firmware while the bios is almost entirely firmware (sometimes even hardware on integrated systems) and the bootloader is almost entirely software (please note this is on bios systems, on uefi the bootstrap loader, bootloader, and bios are VERY interconnected and integrated with each other.)

Comment: ok..In uefi bootstrap loader can start the os entirely. Windows 8 uses uefi.  I think there is also a hidden file in windows called BOOTMGR (boot manager). It loads winload.exe which is windows boot loader. if bootstrap loader can start the os entirely..then why we need boot manager?

Comment: bootstrap loads the mbr or efi partiton that has the boot manager, without that the boot manager can not start as the bios doesn't know where it is

Comment: and until windows 8 windows was able to store its entire boot manager/loader in the mbr, that's why it looked like it was from 1995 up through windows 7, winload.exe is what starts other windows files after it load a kind of windows "kernel" in the boot files that it has that the bios can understand, as the bios can not understand exe files as they are too complex it has to load some libraries beforehand from other boot files.

Comment: It means because of bootstrap loader we can reach to bootloader and bootloader loads the kernel. That's why The bootstrap loader acts as a glue between the bootloader and the kernel, am I right?

Comment: bootstrap is between the bios and the bootloader, so I really don't think it really is the glue between the kernel and the bootloader

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching about it and I had found a conclusion I will share it with you guys (correct me if I'm wrong):

When the power switch is pressed on the CPU starts but it doesn't do anything as no storage devices are detected by it at that time. Then the BIOS comes into play it will do the POST and if the test is successful the BIOS will now search for a way to load operating system.

The bootloader is in the MBR and the bootloader knows how to load the operating system... Here comes the bootstrap loader, it's also a code after BIOS post is successful it contacts the bootstrap loader for helping it to connect with the bootloader to load the OS into RAM... so we can say that the bootstrap loader connects the BIOS (firmware) and the bootloader (software)... so that the BIOS will now know how to load the OS into RAM.